# Add rows to linked hash list

Tags: java, list

I have the follwoing hash map but I need map that I can add duplicate lines,to wihch list should I change it?

I need exactly the same **structure**

```
public static LinkedHashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> moData = new LinkedHashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google have implemented a collection [LinkedHashMultiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultimap.html). Maybe use it?

Comment: @OlafBergin this is not part of the java standard.

Comment: No I don't think there is something in the standard with the exact same structure able to store duplicates. Otherwise google wouldn't have implemented it.